# Algorithm over a p-regular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I'm stuck with this exercise:

Let G = (V, E) be a p-regular bipartite graph
Prove that a cycle can be found in O(|C|) time complexity using a dfs traversal;

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Show your works. Where you stuck$?$

Comment: I dont know how to start, it seem to me that every dfs that i apply find a cycle in O(|V|) at worse